# Fear Conditioning and Hippocampal Remapping

Tags: conditioning, hippocampus

Have there been any studies that explore how much generalization across contexts occurs with fear conditioning?

The "context" that the animal thinks it is in can be observed through the "map" that the hippocampal place cell network is using at a point in time.  Different "contexts" have different "maps".  This is known as [global remapping](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18687478).  I might think that the conditioned fear response would only occur in situations for which there is no hippocampal remapping as compared to the original conditioned environment (i.e. the hippocampus is using the same "map" as the original conditioned environment).

Is there evidence supporting that assumption?

Comment: could you tell me what part is confusing?

Comment: in particular, i imagine that someone that would know the answer to this question would not need more background, but i am happy to clarify anything that is unclear.

Comment: I voted to keep this open, it's just the clustered sentence that makes it a brain teaser :) If you're able to cut that into two sentences it will improve the clarity I think.

Comment: is that better?

Comment: I think that is clearer and an interesting hypothesis